# How can I print text file side by side in python?

Tags: python, printing

I edited "how can I print for loops side by side in python?".

I tried to figure out how to print side by side of my program.

What I want to do is to read each file line by line, and print side by side in final.

There are two problems in my program.

First, text file shows up differently as I expected.

```
The original 'num.text':         My expectation:       The result I got:

0000                             1111                      1
0000                             1111                      1
2222                             2222                      2222
2222                             2222                      2222
```

Second, I don't know how to change my program to print side by side (result1 and result2). I tried 'main def(): print(result1+result2)', but it did not show anything.

```
 num.txt     num2.txt      ->  Print should be:
 0000        2222              1111  2222
 0000        2222              1111  2222
 2222        0000              2222  3333
 2222        0000              2222  3333
```

Here is my program. It's pretty messed up now.

```
def file1():

    f=open("num.txt", "r")

    for line in f:
        for i in range(len(f)):
            l_line = str(f).strip("[]") 
            result1 = (l_line.replace('0','1'))
        print(result1)
file1()

def file2():

    f=open("num2.txt", "r")   
    for line in f:
        for i in range(len(f)):
            data_line = str(f).strip("[]") 
            result2 = (data_line.replace('0','3'))
        print(result2)
file2()
```

So, can someone help me to solve these problems?
It would be nice for me if you explain as you can.

Anyway, thank you for all of the comments and codes below.

Comment: "*It did not work*" What was wrong about it? What happened vs. what you expected?

Comment: `for i in f: f = list(f) ... a = f.rstrip("\n")` I have no idea what your logic here is.

Comment: what are in theses text files? can you make dummy inputs?????

Comment: You define `h` as 3 entirely different things in the second half of the code. First it's a file object, then it's a list of a different file and finally it's a variable integer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do; your code is riddled with errors and odd choices.

```
f=open("textfile1.txt","r")
```

Okay, so **f** is a file object.

```
f = list(f)
```

Now you've converted the file contents to a list? This seems like a VERY inefficient way to go about things, considering you need to iterate over the contents anyway.

```
for v in range(len(f)):
```

Bizarre variable naming aside, you're iterating over each index in **f**.

```
a=f.rstrip("\n")
```

Here's the first major problem!

1. You're overwriting **a** every iteration, so only the last result will be kept.
2. You're not using your index variable **v**.
3. Since you're not using your index, you're trying to strip the ENTIRE LIST, not each line IN the list.

You probably mean something like this:

```
a = f[v].rstrip("\n")
```

### Try this:

```
# declare some list variables.
a = []
b = []

# look up the with keyword. It will handle file closing for you, among other things.
with open("textfile1.txt","r") as f:
    # iterate over every line in the file. 
    # No need for indexes or converting to a list!
    for line in f:
        # strip automatically removes trailing and leading whitespace. 
        # No need to specify \n unless that's ALL you want to remove!
        line = line.strip()
        a.append(line)
```

Copypasta the above and change the variables for the **second file** and list **b**. Then...

```
# iterate over the indexes in a. Assumes that a and b are of the same length.
for ind in range(len(a)):
    print(a[ind], b[ind])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

You are using f when you should be using i because

```
f=open("textfile1.txt","r")
for i in f:    
    i = list(i)
```

Next, you are constantly overwriting a with the entire string f. That is given

```
f = '123456'
list(f)

>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

You are constantly redoing a to be the entire `list(f)` for the length of f. It should be

```
a = list(f.rstrip("\n"))
```

Then you would need to create the empty list a before the loop over f and append each line of f..

```
f=open("textfile1.txt","r")

a = []
for i in f:    
    a.append(list(i.rstrip("\n")))
```

Note that when you finish with f, you should close it rather than letting python `close()` it when it cleans up at the end. it is always better to form good habits even in a trivial example where the bad habit would not hurt.

After you have finished defining a and b, you need to output the data in the way that you want. 'print(a, b)`will print the entire contents of a followed by the entire contents of b. If you want to print one entry from a, followed by one entry from b, the loop over`min(len(a), len(b)` followed by the remainder of whichever list contains the greater number of entries.

An example of what that would show given

```
a = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
b = ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
c = []
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
c

>>> [['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```

If you wanted to make a single list of the two, you would have to loop over a and b appending each element into c individually for each a and b. Thus, you would need a double loop to come up with a list whose elements are each c.

Comment: This doesn't cover half of the problems.`h = list(f)`... well there was no point in `h=open("textfile2.txt","r")`. There are still more on top of that, I doubt you can find the intended output from such a program.

Comment: @roganjosh I am adding and pointing to the various problems as i go. I am saving as I add to the answer so it does not get lost.

Comment: That's fair enough but if you don't know the intended output or the file structure, `for i in f: i = list(i)` might be misguided. Maybe they wanted whole strings of each line. I'd ask for clarification before putting any more effort in tbh :)

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open("textfile1.txt","r")
h=open("textfile2.txt","r")
f_list = [x.rstrip("\n") for x in f]
h_list = [x.rstrip("\n") for x in h]

for i in range(max(len(f_list),len(h_list))):
     print (f_list[i],h_list[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that `rstrip` doesn't exist.
Your second problem is that you can't use `strip` on a list.
Anyway, I wrote a function for what I *think* you want.

```
def print_file_and_strip_newlines(fname):
    rtn = ""
    f = open(fname,"r")
    for ln in f:
        #append to rtn a line, stripped of it's newlines
        rtn = rtn + ln.strip('\n')
    print(rtn)

print_file_and_strip_newlines("textfile1.txt")
print_file_and_strip_newlines("textfile2.txt")
```

textfile1.txt:

```
foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

textfile2.txt

```
bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar
```

Output:

```
foo foo foo foo foo foofoo foo foo foo foo foofoo foo foo foo foo foo
bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a magic `zip` builtin function

```
with open('a.txt') as a_file, open('b.txt') as b_file:
    for a_line, b_line in zip(a_file.readlines(), b_file.readlines()):
        print(a_line.strip(), b_line.strip())

('1', 'a')
('2', 'b')
('3', 'c')
('4', 'd')
('5', 'e')
```

and even better `izip` or `izip_longest` from itertools

better, because they return iterable without reading everything to memory, so one can work on arbitrary length files

```
from itertools import izip

with open('a.txt') as a_file, open('b.txt') as b_file:
    for a_line, b_line in izip(a_file.readlines(), b_file.readlines()):
        print(a_line.strip(), b_line.strip())

('1', 'a')
('2', 'b')
('3', 'c')
('4', 'd')
('5', 'e')
```

izip_longest:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

with open('a.txt') as a_file, open('b.txt') as b_file:
    for a_line, b_line in izip_longest(a_file.readlines(), b_file.readlines()):
        print(a_line.strip() if a_line else a_line, b_line.strip() if b_line else b_line)

('1', 'a')
('2', 'b')
('3', 'c')
('4', 'd')
('5', 'e')
(None, 'f')
(None, 'g')
(None, 'h')
```

simple, clear and pythonic (and this is standard library)